# XML Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I want to use an XML Membership Provider instead of the .NET SqlMembershipProvider.  Is there an open-source project out there I can use?

I've trawled the internet looking for this, but have only found one candidate, [Tiny Providers](http://tinyproviders.codeplex.com/).  But the project has no activity in 2013 and doesn't make use of recent constructs such as XDocument.

My requirement is for a membership provider than only has to handle < 10 users and a role provider with < 10 roles.  I don't need a profile provider. The choice of XML is because I (initially at least) want to edit the XML directly to add users and roles, and deploy just by copying the XML file.

I thought this would be easy to find, as it has all sorts of uses for simple sites.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly look at this:

https://github.com/wilby/XmlMembershipProvider

I did not dig too deep into it, but it is fairly recent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this project, which looked promising, but found it still seems to need a lot of work to be usable. Big chunks of code seem to be copied from the decompiled SqlMembershipProvider, but not consistently.  There is a suite of unit tests, but I couldn't get them all to pass, even after spending quite some hours on this. And I think (most importantly) there are some file-locking issues that trip the code up.